# R Stacked percentage bar plot with two factor variables - How to label the % inside the plot, without counting the NA?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, label, geom-text

I am trying to plot two factor variables and label the results with % inside the plots.
I already tried some recommended codes in previous topics/ questions but I can't solve the problem of the % in the labels.

This is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data2 <- data %>% group_by(anoletivo_cat) %>%
  count(anoletivo_cat, qsd_distrito_nascimento_rec) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n), pct_label = scales::percent(pct))

ggplot(data2[!is.na(data2$qsd_distrito_nascimento_rec),], aes(x= anoletivo_cat, fill = qsd_distrito_nascimento_rec, y = pct)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(pct_label), y = pct), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

And this is the plot I'm getting:

[see the plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAG48.jpg)

As you can see, my labels are counting the % of the NA data (and that's why if we sum the % of the bars it is not 100%, as it should be). So, my question is how can I label the % inside the plot, without counting the NA?

I already ommit them from the plot and the % of the bars of the plot are different from the % I am getting in the labels...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could try filtering out NAs up front, such as:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

data2 <- data %>%
  filter(!is.na(qsd_distrito_nascimento_rec)) %>%
  group_by(anoletivo_cat) %>%
  count(anoletivo_cat, qsd_distrito_nascimento_rec) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n), pct_label = scales::percent(pct))

ggplot(data2, aes(x= anoletivo_cat, fill = qsd_distrito_nascimento_rec, y = pct)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat="identity") +
  geom_text(aes(label = paste(pct_label), y = pct), 
            position = position_fill(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide a set of data in order to have the possibility to check the code. See here: <https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example>

Comment: Thank you Dan Wakeling! It solved the problem :)